# Where should I put my form validation in codeigniter in fat model and thin controller approach?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am confused on where to put the form validation in fat model and thin controller approach in codeigniter. I want to separate the business logic. Is including the form validation destroying the business logic separation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally keep you're form_validation out of the models, however, you don't have to put all the rules in the controller either.

**application/config/form_validation.php**

```
<?php

    //array('field' => '', 'label' => '', 'rules' => '')
    function arrayf($field, $label, $rules)
    {
        return array('field' => $field, 'label' => $label, 'rules' => $rules);
    }

    $config = array(
        'recipients/add' => array(
            arrayf('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|min_length[3]'),
            arrayf('description', 'Description', 'min_length[10]'),
            arrayf('amount', 'Amount', 'required|numeric'),
            arrayf('date', 'Date', 'required|valid_date'),
        ),
        'recipients/delete' => array(
            arrayf('id', 'Id', 'required'),
            arrayf('confirm', 'Confirm', 'required'),
        ),
    );
```

The above is an a basic example.

Then in your controller you would just have:

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run('recipients/add') !== FALSE) {
        //Do whatever
    }
```

Notice how the first validation group has the same index as param passed to

`$this->form_validation->run('recipients/add')`

This way you can use the same validation rules in different controllers without writing them all out again.

**Note**

The function `arrayf()` is used to format the array because otherwise you would have to write out each validation rule with the array keys as well e.g.
`array('field' => '', 'label' => '', 'rules' => '')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, if this worked for you could you mark the question as answered? :)